# nginx rewrite not working?? it simply ignores it

Tags: configuration, nginx, rewrite

i have a wierd problem with nginx, it doesn't want to rewrite...

I have this configuration and i need to pass a hash (40 chars) to a php file
it works with apache mod_rewrite but with nginx it isn't
i even tried to do simple rewrites, it simply doesn't work

```
server {
.........
        location / {
            rewrite ^aa$ /downloadTORRENTZ.php break;
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            rewrite  "^([A-Z0-9]{40})$" /file.php?ddl=$1 break;
        }
}
```

Comment: From @staafl: What OS are you using? I'm sorry for not commenting, but I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 5):

1. Remove "" from your regexp
2. request usually start with `/` so your regexp should look like

   `rewrite  ^/([A-Z0-9]{40})$ /file.php?ddl=$1 break;`
3. Is your hash ALLCAPS? Maybe you should use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
4. 40 characters... It looks like sha1 hash. May be you should simplify regexp to `[0-9A-F]`

Comment: Yep, was missing a preceding `/`